# Copy .rmd file included in a Rstudio addin package to a user defined directory

Tags: r, r-package, file-copying

I have a rstudio addin package located [here](https://github.com/TaylorAndrew/atProjectManageAddins).

One of the addins allows the user to define a directory and it will copy a file that is located in the package to that directory.

the file is located:

```
atProjectManageAddins/inst/Docs/RMarkdownSkeleton.Rmd
```

And I am trying to copy it to the user defined directory with something like this:

```
 file.copy("inst/Docs/RMarkdownSkeleton.Rmd", 
           paste0(Dir, FolderName, "/Reports/", FolderName, "_report.Rmd"))
```

Where I am trying to copy it from where it is in the package, to where the user defines it to be (Based on two separate arguments `Dir` and `FolderName`).

But this doesn't seem to work. My assumption is that I am not referring to the package directory in the correct way. I've tried `./Inst/`, `~/Inst/` and maybe a couple more. My assumption now is that there is a more systematic reason for my inability to get `file.copy()` to work.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Note that if I run the function locally via `source()` and `runGadget()`, it works just fine. Only when the package is installed and I use the RStudio addins GUI where it references the intalled package, does it fail. Thus, I'm quite certain I am not correctly defining the file path for the installed `.Rmd` files.

**Edit:** I've changed to the following, based on Carl's suggestion (as can be seen on github), but the files are still not being copied over.

```
file.copy(system.file("Docs","Rmarkdownskeleton.rmd",package="atProjectManageAd‌​dins"),
 paste0(Dir, FolderName, "/Reports/", FolderName, "_report.Rmd"))
```

Comment: have you tried anything with `file.path`?

Comment: I did. I found a few questions/solutions that used `file.path` for similar questions, but was unable to get a working solution on my end.

Comment: What happens if you try `file.copy("...", "~/Desktop/")`?

Comment: Nothing. I'm fairly certain it has to do with getting the correct file path for the install r package to the .Rmds. I don't think it's an issue for where to copy to files to.

Comment: one more debugging suggestion -- add a dummy function to your package `foo <- function(x) file.exists("./inst/Docs/RMarkdownSkeleton.Rmd")` then run `addin:::foo()` (note the `./` which is missing from your current code)

Comment: `foo()` returns FALSE

Comment: Interesting. I haven't got around to cloning/testing your package yet, but comparing to `data.table`, my source code has `/inst/tests/tests.Rraw` but upon compilation, the installed version of the package no longer has an `/inst` folder but instead in the main directory has `/tests/tests.Rraw`. Could you check out the directory structure of the installed package to make sure this is where the file actually ends up?

Comment: You are correct. In the installed package there is no inst, only the /Docs/ subfolder. I had actually read and investigated this behavior previously, and directly referring to ./Doc/ did not lead to a final solution.

Comment: And `foo()` still returns `FALSE`?

Comment: Also be sure to read [this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html) if you haven't yet

Comment: What about `file.copy(system.file("Docs","Rmarkdownskeleton.rmd",package="atProjectManageAddins",paste0(Dir, FolderName, "/Reports/", FolderName, "_report.Rmd"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system.file` is the best function for getting a file from a package. I believe this should work for you:

```
file.copy(system.file("Docs","Rmarkdownskeleton.rmd",package="atProjectManageAd‌​dins"),
paste0(Dir, FolderName, "/Reports/", FolderName, "_report.Rmd"))
```

Comment: If I simply source the function and use runGadget(), this works, but when I run the updated addin from the installed package, it does not copy them over.

Comment: Hmmm, I will have to investigate further.

Comment: I'm debugging on my end, but any debugging tests I had to the addin that work 'locally', end up not doing anything once installed from the package. I'm wondering if there's any sort of weird permissions issue with addins.

Comment: What happens if you add `print(system.file(package="shiny"))`

Comment: This was the sort of test I was trying to run, I've put the code in the shiny server, as well is the `observeEvent()`, and when I `source()` and `runGadget()` they print to the console what you would expect, but when installed via github and ran through the addins dropdown menu, simply nothing gets printed to the console.

Comment: I created an rstudio addin on my computer that simply is a shiny app with `HTML(system.file(package="shiny"))`, and it works, so you shouldn't have any permissions issues.

Comment: If I had to guess, you haven't reinstalled your package successfully since you changed the code to `system.file` so it isn't working. Clearly the code you run with `runGadget()` is different than what is run when you use the addins dropdown, so I am pretty sure you haven't reinstalled.

Comment: I had no problem getting this to work from addins dropdown menu: https://gist.github.com/carlganz/698101eeeee4179e6f253ae47da675de

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea putting the files in `inst/`.

Use this code to copy the file from the package dir to the current dir :

```
file.copy(from = file.path(path.package("packagename"), "path/to/file"),
      to = file.path("path/to/file"), overwrite = T)
```

`file.path` creates a path by concatenating the strings passed to it (OS-specific separators are automatically added).
`path.package` retrieves the path of a **loaded** package. Files presents in `inst/` are copied at the root of the package dir when installed, thus "path/to/file" here should be the path relative to your `inst/` dir.
`overwrite` can be used to overwrite the file if it already exists.

In your specific case, this should do the trick :

```
file.copy(file.path(path.package("atProjectManageAddins"), "Docs/RMarkdownSkeleton.Rmd", 
          file.path(getwd(), "Reports", paste0(reportName, "_report.Rmd")))
```